# Apply both horizontal & vertical CAGradientLayer Mask to UIScrollView/UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, cagradientlayer

I have a UICollectionView that can be scrolled in both the X and Y axes and I wanted to apply a cool UI effect by adding a bit of fade to any direction that has scrollable content. Hypothetically, the page can display all four edges with fades at the same time or none at all depending on the situation.

I have currently implemented a CAGradientLayer that adds transparency to either the top or the bottom (vertical/y axis) of the page, but I have no clue how I can add a second one, for an additional left and right fade.

```
@IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
let fadeOffset: CGFloat = 10

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    if self.collectionView.layer.mask == nil {

        let maskLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        maskLayer.locations =
            [
                NSNumber(value: 0.0),
                NSNumber(value: 0.2),
                NSNumber(value: 0.8),
                NSNumber(value: 1.0)
            ]

        let bounds = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero,
                                 size: self.collectionView.frame.size)
        maskLayer.bounds = bounds
        maskLayer.anchorPoint = CGPoint.zero

        self.collectionView.layer.mask = maskLayer
    }

    self.scrollViewDidScroll(self.collectionView)
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView == self.collectionView {

        let outerColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0).cgColor
        let innerColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 1).cgColor
        var colors: [CGColor] = []

        let x = scrollView.contentOffset.x
        let y = scrollView.contentOffset.y

        // CALCULATE TOP FADE
        colors += [y + scrollView.contentInset.top <= self.fadeOffset ?
            innerColor : outerColor]
        colors += [innerColor]

        // CALCULATE BOTTOM FADE
        colors += [innerColor]
        colors += [y + scrollView.frame.height >= scrollView.contentSize.height - self.fadeOffset ?
            innerColor : outerColor]

        // APPLY MASK COLORS
        if let mask = scrollView.layer.mask as? CAGradientLayer {
            mask.colors = colors

            CATransaction.begin()

            CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
            mask.position = CGPoint(x, y)

            CATransaction.commit()
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to add another CAGradientLayer for the horizontal axis? Or perhaps there is an even simpler/better way?

Comment: yeah, how do you do this ?!!?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're asking for bilinear gradients. Check out [MKGradientView](https://github.com/maxkonovalov/MKGradientView)